# OSError when using pyopengl glTexImage2D

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, pyopengl

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x.py", line 132, in <module>
    texid = glutils.loadTexture("wall.png")
  File "C:\Users\6e25h\Desktop\Mess\py-opengl-error\glutils.py", line 31, in loadTexture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imgData)
  File "src/latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 311, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "C:\Users\6e25h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000020F6D752000
```

This error I can't solve...
I think I can't describe more detailed
My Code :

```
def loadTexture(filename):
    """load OpenGL 2D texture from given image file"""
    img = Image.open(filename) 
    imgData = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), np.int8)
    texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imgData)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    return texture
```

How I can solve this problem ?Help me ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images doesn't seem to have 4 color channels. Most likely the image has just 3 color channels. You've to specify the format `GL_RGB` rather than `GL_RGBA` in [`glTexImage2D`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glTexImage2D.html). For instance:

```py
format = GL_RGB if imgData.shape[1] == 3 else GL_RGBA
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, 
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imgData)
```